# Excel VBA For Nested Loop with IF and variables

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, variables, nested-loops

I have 10 vacuum sense lines that can be used (VacLine(x) variable), those are odd numbers (from 1 to 19) located on a Multiple Selection ListBox. Depending on the selection of these options, I would like to assign a single value to each of the 10 VacLine(x) variables.

[image]

The driving number in this case would be selected from the ListBox, once that number is found, it should assign it to the VacLine(x) and then go to the Next x from the last selected value it counted. The minimum selection is 1, and the max is 10, and not in a specific order.

So for example shown, I selected 3, 17 & 19 then VacLine1 = 3, VacLine2 = 17 & VacLine3 = 19, VacLine4 to VacLine10 = 0.
VacLinesList is my ListBox.
VacLine(x) are my variables Dimmed as `Dim VacLine(1 To 10) As Integer`

```
    With VacTC.VacuumLinesList
    
    For q = 1 To 10
        v = 0
        For v = v To .ListCount - 1
            If VacLine(q) = "" Then
                If .Selected(v) Then
                VacLine(q) = .List(v)
                Exit For
                End If
            Exit For
            End If
        Next v
    Next q
    
End With
```

I don't know how to force it to assign the value found to VacLine(x) and then go to the next x but starting at the last selected value found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `VacuumLinesList` is your ListBox and `VacLine` is your array (already `Dimmed`)

```
With VacuumLinesList
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    j = LBound(VacLine)
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            VacLine(j) = .List(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ' produce test output
    For i = LBound(VacLine) To UBound(VacLine)
        Debug.Print i, VacLine(i)
    Next i
End With
```

... `i` is the `ListBox` item index and `j` is the array index

Comment: That's correct, VacuumLinesList is my ListBox, VacLine is my array already Dimmed as Dim VacLine(1 To 10) As String, but I input the code and didn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you clarify 'didn't work' ... was there an error or output not matching what you expected?

Comment: No error output, the "Debug.Print" didn't print owt.

Comment: Could it be because of how I'm dimming the variables? Instead of VacLine1, VacLine2, etc. Just VacLine(1 to 10) and then have the code loop through those? While assigning the selected value from the ListBox?

Comment: So where did you put the code? For example if the ListBox is in a UserForm and if you have a CommandButton that you click when the relevant items are selected in the ListBox (and maybe closes the UserForm) then it could go in the Click event handler of that CommandButton?

Comment: VacLine needs to be an array eg `Dim VacLine(1 to 10) As Variant` ... make sure you have `Option Explicit` in the Module hosting your code

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't have the Option Explicit, but when I added it, the "With VacuumLinesList" popped an error, as variable wasn't defined but before I added the Option Explicit it was working fine.

Comment: Always include `Option Explicit` ... it hides errors and makes you think your code is okay when it isn't!

Comment: First of all, I wanted to thank you for the help and the time you invested in this. I made it work after a while, all I did was call the form where "VacuumLinesList" was on the code you provided. So it ended up being "With VacTC.VacuumLinesList" I also fixed my code with your recommendation of Option Explicit, so thanks! @JohnM